# Td innerText element VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have this code :

```
<tbody id="frm:r:0:s:tbody_element">
<tr>
    <td>
    <img id="frm:r:0:s:0:img_2" src="/example/img/ic_small_min.gif" 
       onclick="Expand(getID(this.id,'f'))" style="cursor: pointer;" /> 
    - My Items
    <span id="frm:r:0:s:0:f" style="DISPLAY: none;">
          <input type="checkbox" name="frm:r:0:s:0:bcb" id="frm:r:0:s:0:bcb"  
           value="true" onclick="checkAll(this.form, this)" />
           <table id="frm:r:0:s:0:mcb">     
          <tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" name="frm:r:0:s:0:mcb" 
                    value="H321" />&#160;List</label></td>
           </tr>        
          <tr><td>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="frm:r:0:s:0:mcb"
               value="H318" />&#160;Edit</label></td>
           </tr>        
          <tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" name="frm:r:0:s:0:mcb"
                     value="H310" />&#160;Delete</label>
           </td></tr>
```

But I try to *getElementsbyid("frm:r:0:s:tbody_element").innerText* and I get :

**My items List Edit Delete**

Instead of only the

**My items**

why?

What I want to do is get only the : My Items

I don't want to get all the text inside the element.

Comment: The table body innerText contains all the text displayed in the table, so your results are expected. What do you want to do?

Comment: i edit the post to give you the response for that ... but i only want the My items 


not every text displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'if doc = the loaded document
Set tb = doc.getElementById("frm:r:0:s:tbody_element")
Set els = tb.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).ChildNodes
Debug.Print els(1).NodeValue ' "- My Items"
```

Comment: strange when i try to assign els i always get a error "a object is required" but in the debugger if i watch the tb variable the definition is ... object

Comment: soo if tb is a object i don't know why excel don't recognise the type on the els = tb.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).ChildNodes

Comment: OK manage to put it to work but i had to do it all in one line :D